# Control screen brightness of HP Pavillon DV 9643 EG 17 with OpenSUSE 12.2

Tags: linux, graphics-card, bios, opensuse-12.2

I'm running an HP Pavillon DV 9643 EG 17 with OpenSUSE 12.2 and KDE.

I don't know how to adjust the brightness of the screen.

Would looking at `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings` help?

Comment: You should be able to control it using the KDE brightness settings, just have a look in the Kontrol Center.